# Dealing with manpage search

Tags: man

It seems that `man -K` does not search the formatted output, but the markup source. For example

```
 man -K warranties
```

gives many manpages which do not contain the string `warranties`, like xcalc(1). Also, searching for strings containing special characters is very difficult:

```
 man -K 7 '\f'
```

gives a lot of pages not containing `\f`.

```
 man -K 7 '\\f'
```

does not seem to display false positives, but it also does not display ascii(7), which contains the string `\f`.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html) man-manual, your first example would search for the literal **`\f`**, which you would find in most manual pages for changing fonts, e.g.,

```
The international counterpart of ASCII is known as ISO 646.
.LP
The following table contains the 128 ASCII characters.
.LP
C program \f(CW\(aq\eX\(aq\fP escapes are noted.
.if t \{\
.ft CW
\}
.TS
l l l l l l l l.
```

which shows a section of `ascii(7)` from Debian's 3.44-1 package for `manpages`.  This file contains no other instances of **`\f`**, and none of **`\\f`**.

Since FreeBSD `man` lacks the **`-K`** option, and OSX `ascii.7` has no font-switching using **`\f`**, it's likely that you're referring to Linux.  The Linux **`man`** program supports regular expressions—as an option **`--regex`**.  By default, it does not use regular expressions.

Since you are looking for the **formatted** **`\f`**, you should look for the markup which produces that pair of characters.  In `ascii.7`, the line showing

```
014   12    0C    FF  '\f' (form feed)        114   76    4C    L
```

is produced by

```
012     10      0A      LF  \(aq\en\(aq (new line)      112     74      4A      J
```

That is, it is using the groff macro **`\en`**, which you can search for:

```
man -K 7 '\en'
```

and get a much shorter output (5811 lines on my Debian 7 versus 57322).  Just the header/footer lines is enough to show the result here:

```
ASCII(7)                    Linux Programmer's Manual                    ASCII(7)
Linux                               2009-02-12                           ASCII(7)
COPY(7)                  PostgreSQL 9.1.22 Documentation                  COPY(7)
PostgreSQL 9.1.22                   2016-05-27                            COPY(7)
CPUSET(7)                   Linux Programmer's Manual                   CPUSET(7)
Linux                               2008-11-12                          CPUSET(7)
GITCORE-TUTORIAL(7)                 Git Manual                GITCORE-TUTORIAL(7)
Git 1.7.10.4                        03/19/2016                GITCORE-TUTORIAL(7)
GROFF_CHAR(7)                                                       GROFF_CHAR(7)
Groff Version 1.21                 25 June 2012                     GROFF_CHAR(7)
GROFF_MDOC(7)          BSD Miscellaneous Information Manual         GROFF_MDOC(7)
GROFF_TRACE(7)                                                     GROFF_TRACE(7)
Groff Version 1.21                 25 June 2012                    GROFF_TRACE(7)
MAN(7)                      Linux Programmer's Manual                      MAN(7)
Linux                               2012-08-05                             MAN(7)
```

This of course depends on knowing the relevant markup (and there's likely to be *different* ways to express the same thing).  The reason why `man` looks at the markup is that it cannot rely upon being able to search *formatted* manual pages.

A while back, it was common to have `catman` directories which stored formatted manual pages because

- formatting manual pages was slow, and
- some vendors did not distribute formatted manual pages (or some, such as Sun, provided markup in non-nroff form, complicating things)

One could make a [KWIC index](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/lang/python/examples/kwic/web/theory.html) of all of the words in all of the manual pages as-formatted, but that would still

- take a lot of space, and
- take a lot of time to generate

Comment: Thanks. That settles *this* case. I should've explained it more carefully: What I mean is what can we do in general about this problem? Another problem are the annoying false positives because `man -K` searches even the comments of the unformatted source!